# JQUERY - JSON Result assign it to pre populate form fields on when select is selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have this requirement form business to Save Searches, allowing users to use saved search data and rerun the search. I have saved the search in database as JSON object. Problem is when users select already saved search via using Select - Dropdown, the form should pre populates all the selections that were saved with search.  When I am trying to alert the key value within populate function - it always show key as 0 and value as whole JSON object. What am I missing here ?

Sample of returned JSON request from database looks like:  {"affects":["153","503","537"],"suspect":["101","108"],"state":[],"zip_code":[],"analysis_date_max":["",""],"last_modified_date_min":["",""]}

Here is my existing code:
//START OF PROBLEM CODE

```
function populate(frm, data) {
        var obj  = $.parseJSON(data);
        //alert (data);
        //alert (frm);

        alert (obj);
        $.each(obj, function(key, value){
            alert(key + ' is ' + value);
        $('[name='+key+']', frm).val(value);

      });
}

// END OF PROBLEM CODE
    $('#search_dataselect').on('change', function()
    {
       getSearchData(this.value);

    });

    function getSearchData(search_id) {

    if (!isNaN(parseInt(search_id))) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/index.cgi?p=json&t=SavedSearch&search_id="+search_id, 
            success: function(result){
            var data  = result;
            populate('#formSearch',data);

            },
        });
    }
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: Most of the controls on the search page are MULTISELCT dropdowns

Answer (score 0):

It appears your data is not serialized.
Try this:

```
success: function(result) {

var data  = JSON.stringify(result);
populate('#formSearch', data);

}
```

An example for using JSON.stringify()

https://jsfiddle.net/3u6mrft1/